# Getting average/mean over a set number of days in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets say i have this data frame

```
Date           DayOfWeek    Url    Hits
09/01/2016     Thursday     url1   3
09/01/2016     Thursday     url2   5
09/01/2016     Thursday     url3   4
09/02/2016     Friday       url1   7
09/02/2016     Friday       url3   6
09/03/2016     Saturday     url2   9
09/03/2016     Saturday     url1   5
09/04/2016     Sunday       url2   6
09/07/2016     Wednesday    url10  4
09/07/2016     Thursday     url2   3
09/07/2016     Thursday     url4   2
09/07/2016     Thursday     url5   3
09/07/2016     Thursday     url1   3
09/08/2016     Friday     url1   3
09/08/2016     Friday     url4   3
09/08/2016     Friday     url5   2
09/08/2016     Friday     url8   6
09/09/2016     Saturday     url2   1
09/09/2016     Saturday     url3   2
09/09/2016     Saturday     url5   4
09/09/2016     Saturday     url1   8
09/14/2016     Thursday     url1   3
09/147/2016     Thursday     url2   2
09/14/2016     Thursday     url3   3
```

I want to get the busiest day of the week in terms of the number of unique url visited. For example, in the data frame there are 3 thursdays, first thursday has 3 unique urls visited, second thursday has 4 and the last thursday has 3... what I plan to do is, sum the number of urls = 3 + 4 + 3/ (# of thursdays = 3) = ave number of unique urls for this day....

For Friday, it would be 2 urls for the first then for the second, there are 4, computation will be 2 + 4 / number of fridays in the data set = 2

I'm trying to resolve this via dplyr. I'm trying to use group_by, but i can't seem to determine the right function combinations to arrive at what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We get the number of distinct 'Url' ('N') for each 'Date' and 'DayOfWeek' (`n_distinct`) and get the `mean` of 'N' for each 'DayofWeek'.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Date, DayOfWeek) %>%
    summarise(N = n_distinct(Url)) %>% 
    group_by(DayOfWeek) %>% 
    summarise(N = mean(N))
# DayOfWeek        N
#      <chr>    <dbl>
#1    Friday 3.000000
#2  Saturday 3.000000
#3    Sunday 1.000000
#4  Thursday 3.333333
#5 Wednesday 1.000000
```

Comment: The `DayOfWeek` in the first `group_by` might be redundant? Wouldn't that be taken care of in `Date` anyway?

Comment: @rosscova If we don't use `DayOfWeek', it will get the length of 'unique' 'Url' for the whole 'Thursday's.  I guess the OP wanted to do this separately

Comment: @rosscova I think you are right, but we will not get the 'DayOfWeek' info

Comment: OK, so it's just to make sure the `DayOfWeek` column is carried through to the next step then?

Comment: @rosscova Or else I may have to resort to `mutate`